# Is there a better way of Chef recipe coding on the below code?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, postgresql-9.2, recipe

I am trying to do a base backup of PostgreSQL. My code is a simple Bash run in Ruby. It will just do a basebackup and tar it into a /tmp/(DIR)

```
 file "/tmp/basebackup.sh" do
 user "postgres"
 mode 0755
 content <<-EOH
     su - postgres
     export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin
     su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/initdb -D /tmp/pg_data/ -s --no-locale --encoding=UTF8"  - postgres
     su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl -D /tmp/pg_data -l logfile start" - postgres
     su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/psql -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('initial backup for SR')" template1" - postgres
     tar -cvf pg_base_backup.tar /tmp/pg_data
     su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/psql -c "SELECT pg_stop_backup()" template1" - postgres
     exit 0
 EOH
 end

 execute "/tmp/basebackup.sh"  do
      ignore_failure true
      action :run
 end
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby supports `__END__` which is used to mark the end of the runnable script. Anything after that isn't seen by the running program, but can be accessed using the `DATA` file handle, which can be `read`, like a normal file. Try this bit of code to see it work:

```
File.open('trashme.txt', 'w') do |content|
  content << DATA.read
end

__END__
su - postgres
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin
su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/initdb -D /tmp/pg_data/ -s --no-locale --encoding=UTF8"  - postgres
su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/pg_ctl -D /tmp/pg_data -l logfile start" - postgres
su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/psql -c "SELECT pg_start_backup('initial backup for SR')" template1" - postgres
tar -cvf pg_base_backup.tar /tmp/pg_data
su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/psql -c "SELECT pg_stop_backup()" template1" - postgres
exit 0
```

I'd use that feature to move the shell script outside the normal Ruby/chef script for maintenance and clarity.